# QEMU with multichannel audio (5.1 and so on)

Tags: qemu

I have a 5.1 setup using the integrated sound chip that is working on Arch and would like to use it inside an emulated Windows with QEMU

I see patches like [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2015-08/msg02497.html) mentioning support but the arguments are not recognised. I fear that said patches where never merged.

Is it possible to add a 5.1 *emulated* sound card to the vm?

Comment: Just as I feared, these patches have not been merged as proof by the [first proposal in the 2017 GSOC](http://wiki.qemu.org/Google_Summer_of_Code_2017#QEMU_audio_backend). I guess if I want to use 5.1 audio I'll have to apply the patches myself to the appropiate version. Should I answer the question in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with help of Zoltán the original author I've managed to make this work.
He keeps a github repository with a qemu fork and all of his work fully functioning [here](https://github.com/DirtYiCE/qemu/tree/audio-51), although under an older qemu verison.

First fetch a copy of said repository and compile it.

These are my configure options, use "--help" to see what to add or remove:

```
../configure --python=/usr/bin/python2 --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --audio-drv-list=oss,alsa,sdl,pa
```

After you've compiled everything you can execute qemu with the following flags:

```
-audiodev pa,id=asdf,out.mixeng=off -device usb-audio,audiodev=asdf,multi=on
```

This will expose an usb audio device that supports multichannel audio that gets outputted to pulse audio.

Of note on the previous line, mixeng has to be off for the setup to work, multi "on" to use the multichannel audio device and (the part I had trouble) usb audiodev has to match an id of a declared audiodev ("asdf" in this case).

The author has commented a lot of the options in qemu "--help".

Hopefully someone will pick the work at [2017 GSOC audio work](http://wiki.qemu.org/Google_Summer_of_Code_2017#QEMU_audio_backend) proposal so that it finally gets merged.

Comment: At some time you experience stutters?

Comment: Not with audio out, just some clicks every so often, not something I would fuss about (and I'm picky with the sound). Microphone however was an absolute mess, and ended up buying a cheapo usb sound card just for that, and even then it gave me some troubles.

Comment: I figured out qxl device for the mouse was increasing the occurrences but after that, was like you pointed, some specific times, when windows UAC show up and so on.